# Why does my SQL Server Express (2014) connection break after restarting my computer?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, connectivity

For some reason when I install SQL Server Express (2014), it works fine for a while (usually a day or two), and then quits allowing me to sign in.

I'm not just talking about remotely here, either. Even through the Management Studio, I get:

[image]

I sign in using Windows Authentication, and as I said, it DOES WORK fine for a little bit, and then, even though I haven't made any changes, of any kind to the system, the program, or even the database it's linked to, it just decides to quit working until I uninstall/reinstall SQL Server Express (2014), and then it works fine again for a day or two.

I've done this 3 times now, and this is the third time it's decided to spontaneously quit working.

I've tried all the tricks on this website (accepts remote connections, firewall, connection string, starting SQL Browser, ): http://www.sswug.org/articlesection/default.aspx?TargetID=44331 but everything seems in order, and again, it works for a while after install each time.

What could possibly cause this to happen? I don't know where else to look. Should I just go with the (seemingly) more stable SQL Server CE (despite its limitations). Should I go with SQL Server Express 2012, instead? Is 2014 just buggy?

Comment: No, 2014 is not buggy, and no, CE is not better or more stable - it's actually deprecated. Sounds like the SQL Server service is stopping for some reason (check the Windows event log) or isn't starting up automatically after a reboot (check the startup properties in SQL Server Configuration Manager).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yeah, I think you're right. I think I've rebooted between each of these SQL Server fails. I see the SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) service is stopped, but it also won't let me start it as it errors (either through windows services or Sql Server Manager). I will check the event logs and see if it tells me anything.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Okay, I think I'm in the right place, in Computer Management, I'm in Event Viewer, Windows Logs, and Application. There I can see the error (Event ID 63) "SideBySide" Here is the text it displays: [Activation context generation failed for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\CopyDatabaseWizard.exe".Error in manifest or policy file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\CopyDatabaseWizard.exe" on line 8. The value "1.0" of attribute "version" in element "assemblyIdentity" is invalid.]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is very likely related to your machine; not SQL Server 2014 itself.

A few things I would start checking when the same issue happens:

1. SQL Server Error Log
2. Windows Event Log
3. SQL Server Service Account state and password (is the account disabled or locked?)
4. Try pinging the IP of SQL Server
5. Try connecting by forcing TCP, using `tcp:192.168.0.1,1433` (replace 192.168.0.1 with the actual IP address)
6. Try running SysInternal's Process Monitor to see what is happening exactly while attempting the login process.
7. Is the Kerberos SPN set correctly?

I very much doubt the SQL Server team would release buggy products which even starts failing at login.  The logs will definitely give a clue about what is happening, perhaps the installation logs also show something relevant.

Comment: Thanks Max for the edits,I was typing from small screen phone

Answer (score 1):

can you try a `get-service *sql*` from Powershell next time it stops so you can see if it is running?  If not, can you get us the application logs for SQL Server from `eventvwr.msc` so we can review it?  Something might be causing the service to stop.  If it isn't, then perhaps your SQL Browser service is stopped. We will need the logs to help you out further.

Just in general be careful with jumping to a older/different product due to what might be a minor issue that isn't related to the product at large.  You could waste a lot of time redoing everything then run into a similar problem and jump ship again or get really frustrated.

Comment: You force start the service - and the service starts successfully? Or doesn't?

Comment: It doesn't. It fails. I checked the event logs and I get a Event ID of 63 "SideBySide" Error. The text reads as follows [Activation context generation failed for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\CopyDatabaseWizard.exe".Error in manifest or policy file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\CopyDatabaseWizard.exe" on line 8. The value "1.0" of attribute "version" in element "assemblyIdentity" is invalid.]

Comment: @AaronBertrand When I try to force start the service (SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)) I get the following message "The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion. Consult the event  log or other applicable error logs for details." To which it shows an error 63 (SideBySide) error. I looked here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3573.event-id-63-sidebyside.aspx and it says to possibly reinstall C++ which I have, but to no avail.

Comment: What is your operating system? Is your operating system x86 or x64? Are you running the x86 or x64 version of SQL Express?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Okay, I've got it. Apparently it was trying to logon with a specific account (not sure what account it thought it should have since I've only been logging on using Windows Authentication), but after I resolved that and restarted the service, I was able to get back on. I'm assuming I don't need the SQL Browser, since it's still disabled but I'm logging on just fine?

Anyway, I really appreciate the help, I'll just have to check it again at startup. If you want to write this up as an answer, I'll be happy to upvote and accept.

Comment: Browser is used so that remote connections can map a named instance to a port. Since you're connecting locally it should be using shared memory and thus SQL browser is irrelevant.

Comment: Yup what Aaron said, just keep in mind browser will be relevant if you try to connect remotely to that machine.  Your question was mentioning that you use both and it fails.  If you specify a named instance and don't hard code a port number you'll want to leave Browser running.  I believe this is true for Express as well.

Comment: @VoidKing Void, the 'instance not found' error will not pop up if you are trying to authenticate to the DB server and it can actually see it.  In that case you'd get an authentication error.  This error is specifically stating it couldn't connect to SQL Server.  Thus if you did have a user issue that resolved this error, it would have to be some service user instead of authenticating user.

Comment: @AliRazeghi Thanks for letting me know about the SQL Browser service being needed in the future, as eventually this will be on a server, but since WebMatrix will actually be connecting to it (on the same server) I'm not sure if this will be needed (since WebMatrix doesn't need it on my local machine, either), but I will watch out for this in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @AliRazeghi In regards to your last comment, can you please explain more of what you mean? It seems like I might understand you correctly, but I'm not sure. Are you saying this error will be a recurring issue most likely?

Comment: Sure.  Please try to login to the server from SSMS using SQL Authentication with a bad password.  You'll get an error stating login failed for user 'user'. Error: 18456.  If you don't have mixed mode enabled, try logging in with a windows user that doesn't have permissions granted to CONNECT to the SQL Server.  You'll get a very similar error.  Then try to log in to the Server typing in a fake server name or bad instance name, but with the correct user. You'll then get the error you have shared.  The error you're getting is stating "I can't even find the SQL Server to authenticate to it".

Comment: @AliRazeghi Okay, I see, yeah. Thank you so much for the help!